# regular-expressions to match all the relative path in string

Tags: javascript, regex

How to write a regex to filter all the string with relative path format i.e.starts with ser_ver/ and ends with .dat and inbetween may have _,-,/ like following,

```
file1 ser_ver\sha-re\subfolder_1.dat
file2 ser_ver\sha-re\folder1\subfolder_1\subfolder_2.dat
file3 server\sha-re\complex\subfolder_1.dat
file4 server\sha-re\5555AB12\subfolder_1\subfolder_2\subfolder_3.dat
```

expected:

```
ser_ver\sha-re\subfolder_1.dat
ser_ver\sha-re\folder1\subfolder_1\subfolder_2.dat
```

Comment: \ and / are not the same character.    Which is it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Something like this...

```
/\bser_ver\/[\w\/-]+\.dat\b/
```

Explanation...

```
\b
```

Zero-width word boundary, matches between a "word" and "non-word" character. Doesn't actually add anything to the match, just anchors it so it can't start or end in the middle of a word.

```
[\w\/-]+
```

Matches one or more characters from a to z, A to Z, underscore, dash or forward slash.

```
\.
```

Literal `.`.

So it matches...

```
\b ser_ver/ [\w\/-]+ .dat \b
```

Word boundary followed by `ser_ver/` then one or more characters from a to z, A to Z, underscore, dash or forward slash, followed by `.dat` and then another word boundary.

All this assumes that you're working with forward slashes as stated in your comments.

As mentioned by someone else in the comments, your examples actually use backslash, so this would need updating if you're using those.

Like this...

```
/\bser_ver\\[\w\\-]+\.dat\b/
```

Or allow both...

```
/\bser_ver[\\\/][\w\\\/-]+\.dat\b/
```

Comment: /\bser_ver\\[\w\\-]+\.dat\b/g  this exp does exactly. Thank you so much!

Comment: The downvotes are because I answered a question that you folks don't like or what?